# Change url of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the controller tencet and the method index.

Url:

```
localhost:3000/tencet/index
```

I want change url of this page to

```
localhost:3000/admin
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you post the corresponding route in the routes file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming site is your domain and not a namespace...

In your config/routes.rb file:

```
get '/admin', to: 'tencet#index'
```